# phpMyAdmin SQL query bug

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm creating my site database in phpMyAdmin and I have a problem. When I search for something that has `@` in it, I don't get the result. For example:

[This is my database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygwe7.jpg) There two queries that I test with:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = 'pleaseWorkNow@gmail.com';
```

And I get no results. When I try with the email that is without `@` I get the right result.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = 'peporapa';
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: what is that column's type and db collation?

Comment: PHP tag was fail, removed. To the second question: email-varchar(255)-armscii8_general_ci

Comment: check for whitespace then. I can't see this failing.

Comment: Please edit question and include a short sample of your database, else this question will be useless when link dies.

Comment: then try `'pleaseWorkNow\@gmail.com';`

Comment: How are you testing this query? I try with phpMyAdmin 4.5.1 (SQL query box) and it works.

Comment: I'm on 4.3.11, also didn't work with the \@ mechanic.

Comment: does a user with email 'pleaseWorkNow@gmail.com' actually exist? Verify this by doing `select * from users where email like '%pleaseWork%';`

Comment: @GoshoPepoto I was asking "how are you testing", hoping you would tell me that you use phpMyAdmin's SQL query box. By the way, phpMyAdmin 4.3.11 is outdated.